# Why are these cam pulleys constructed differently?

Tags: toyota, camshaft, pulley, 5vz, cam-timing

I am about midway done with changing the timing belt & water pump on my 99 Toyota, which features a 6-cylinder 5VZ-FE engine. After getting the front timing cover off, I noticed that the passenger-side cam pulley has a raised rear lip, but the driver-side pulley does not.  What is the reason for this difference?

**Passenger-side cam pulley, with raised rear lip:**
[image]

**Driver-side cam pulley, without raised rear lip:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raised rear lip is used to align the timing belt. It only needs one of these to keep the belt aligned, thus the difference.